# Show/hide content for menu sublink and close the content when click next new link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a solution, it must work in IE also, that I can have the content hidden and then when you click one of the menu items it shows the content. However, the content doesn't hide until a user clicks on the next link...

Comment: <li><a href="#">Web</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" class="a1" >Designing</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="a2">Development</a></li>
  </ul> 
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">IT</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" class="a1">Sales & Service</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="a2">CCTV</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="a3">DVR</a></li>
  </ul> 
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">ITES</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" class="a1">BPO</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="a2">Online Portal</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="a3">Online Marketing</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>

Comment: @Sreeram www.whynotedityourpostinstead&includethesnippet.com

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link
http://jsfiddle.net/varada/YLX9x/

you can use jquery hide() and show() functions for that.

Let the id of div that is to be hidden be hidden_div, let menu item be menu_item, next button be next,

Import the jquery.js
and write the ready function as below..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#menu_item').click(function() {
$('#hidden_div').show();
});

$('#next').click(function() {
$('#hidden_div').hide();
});


});
```

or if you mean the content be visible till he click the next link on the menu item, add a class name say, menu_class to the menu items and write the code

```
$('.menu_class').click(function() {
    $('#hidden_div').hide();
    });
```

instead of `$('#next').click(function()`

if you have a menu like

```
<ul>
<li class='menu_class'>item 1</li>
<li id='menu_item' >item 2</li>
<li class='menu_class'>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

and the div

```
<div id='hidde_div' style='display:none'>
content
</div>
```

then if you click item 2 the div will get displayed. and if you click item 1 or item 3 it will get hidden. make sure you are using the code  `$('.menu_class').click(function() {`

Comment: can u explain me wt is #menu_item, #hidden_div, #next im new to developing side... help me...

Comment: sure..#menu_item means the <li> has the id menu_item. ie, <li id='menu_item'> similarly .menu_class means <li class='menu_class'>

Comment: #hidden_div and #next means??

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<li class="main"><a href="#">Web</a> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="a1">Designing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a2">Development</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="main"><a href="#">IT</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="a1">Sales & Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a2">CCTV</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a3">DVR</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="main"><a href="#">ITES</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="a1">BPO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a2">Online Portal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a3">Online Marketing</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>​
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li  ul:not(:first)').hide();
    $('ul li').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.main').next().find('ul').show();
        $(this).closest('ul').hide();
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7QheB/